# Wordpress count galleries into a post

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I'm adding many galleries to a post. Here is an exemple of one of my post:

```
[gallery ids="47,48,49"]
[gallery ids="49,47,44"]
[gallery ids="419,147,414"]
```

I would like to know if there is a way to count and retrieve the number of different galleries  of my post in my single.php file?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of galleries? You mean [gallery] or any plugin's gallery?